# MongoDB query to Retrieve all the rows which contain a particular element inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to using MongoDb and I'm stuck in this query ,
I want to retrieve all the rows that have small size available

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
  "sizes":["small","medium","large"]
},
{
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c22942f08fe4193"),
  "sizes":["small"]
},
{
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4199"),
  "sizes":["medium","large"]
},
```

I want all the rows that have small size available i.e

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c12942f08fe4192"),
  "sizes":["small","medium","large"]
},
{
  "_id":ObjectId("562e7c594c22942f08fe4193"),
  "sizes":["small"]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what commands you have already tried, but ,maybe try using this command:

```
myCursor = db.inventory.find( { 'sizes': "small" } )
```

Since this will only show you the first 20 documents, you can place a loop:

```
while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
    print(tojson(myCursor.next()));
}
```

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read_queries/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$elemMatch`

```
xxx.find(
   { sizes: { $elemMatch: { $eq:"small" } } }
)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
db.sales.aggregate([
 {
    $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$items",
                as: "item",
                cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.sizes", small] }
            }
          }
      }
   }
}
])
```

or

```
db.users.find({sizes': "small"});
```